# Can I call hypersetup twice?

Tags: hyperref, metadata

I have nested latex classes.  A base class sets company-wide styles and contains this:

```
\ProvidesClass{companydoc}
\LoadClass{report}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan,
    bookmarks=true,
}
```

The next class is for reports that need approval. It needs to add a few custom meta-data fields:

```
\ProvidesClass{approvaldoc}
\LoadClass{companydoc}

\necommand{\SetApprovalData}[2]{
  \hypersetup{
    pdfinfo={
      ApprovingManager={#1},
      ApprovalDate={#2}
    }
  }
}
```

Will `approvaldoc`'s `\hypersetup` override or augment `companydoc`'s `\hypersetup`?

Assuming augmentation is possible, If I want to go even further, the next class is specifically for expense reports:

```
\ProvidesClass{expensereport}
\LoadClass{approvaldoc}

\newcommand{\SetExpenseTotal}[1]{
  \hypersetup{
    pdfinfo={
      ExpenseTotal={#1}
    }
  }
}
```

Here, I assume that we will override `approvaldoc`'s `pdfinfo`.  If so, can I get the current value of `pdfinfo`, so I can append data to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use it as often as you want. With classical hyperref the pdfinfo is set at the end of the first page. So if you run this document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={ABC=aaa}}
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={CDE=ccc}}
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={CDE=ddd}}
\begin{document}
aaa
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={FGH=fff}}

\newpage 

bbbb
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={XYZ=xxx}}
\end{document}
```

you will get these entries

```
/ABC(\376\377\000a\000a\000a)
/CDE(\376\377\000d\000d\000d)
/FGH(\376\377\000f\000f\000f)
```

So the second CDE wins, and the XYZ on the last page is lost.

If you use the new pdfmanagement by adding `\DocumentMetadata` at the begin, then the new hyperref driver will set the Info dictionary at the end of the document and the XYZ is used too.

```
\DocumentMetadata{} 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={ABC=aaa}}
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={CDE=ccc}}
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={CDE=ddd}}
\begin{document}
aaa
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={FGH=fff}}

\newpage 

bbbb
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={XYZ=xxx}}
\end{document}
```

gives

```
/ABC <FEFF006100610061>
/CDE <FEFF006400640064>
/FGH <FEFF006600660066>
/XYZ <FEFF007800780078>
```

Be aware that in PDF 2.0 the Info Dictionary is deprecated and such data should be set in the XMP metadata instead.

Comment: Your last sentence is interesting.  I'm on Debian 11 and `pdfinfo out.pdf` gives `PDF version: 1.5` and does not display the metadata.  If I use `pdftk out.pdf dump_data` I see my metadata in `InfoKey` and `InfoValue` fields.  Is this related to Info Dictionary vs XMP metadata?  How can I get hypersetup to set the XMP metadata instead?

Comment: you can use hyperxmp to add XMP metadata (that is an XML file embedded in the pdf), but it will not honor your local data in pdfinfo, you would have to use other keys, see the documentation. It is not really extensible, so if you want to add really your own XML data, you  must use the new code in the pdfmanagement but this would require a really current TeX system, and you would have to discuss with me the interfaces ;-). I can't know if you really need that, perhaps pdf 1.5 and Info is fine for you.

Comment: `hyperxmp` looks significantly more complicated, especially with custom fields.  I think pdf1.5 is fine.  Thanks.